# Issue with Image Url when it is on live server

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, styles, stylesheet

i am facing issue with my root directory name while applying images on my application

this is css:

```
label.css-label-checkbox {
    background-image: url('/Images/checkbox.png');
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

while this is using on my page:

```
    <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxApprove" id="cbxCallBackFrequency" style="width: 80px;" class="css-checkbox-Approve" />
          <label for="cbxCallBackFrequency" class="css-label-checkbox">CallBack Frequency</label>
   </div>
```

while the application running in local its working fine(Getting Images)

But when i hosted on live

```
http://192.168.1.29/CSPV3/Account/index
```

on Browser console i fount that `http://192.168.1.29/Images/checkbox.png file not found`

i tried all different ways like

```
/Images/checkbox.png
~/Images/checkbox.png
/../Images/checkbox.png
 Images/checkbox.png
```

But for Temp/emergency situation i wrote it as `/CSPV3/Images/checkbox.png` i know this is the worst thing to wrote in this way,

please help me to get out of this problem with urls

[image]

Comment: show your directory hirarchey

Comment: I justed added image of my application Directory hirarchey

Answer (score 0):

If the Images directory is one level up from where the CSS files are located, use:

`../Images/image-name-here.extension`

Note that the path does **not** start with a forward-slash.

As an aside, if the images are small and you don't need to support older versions of IE, consider installing the [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension and using it to Base64-encode your images. Then, file paths become moot.